# ¿Por qué no me deja eliminar el item en mi código con Node.js y Express?

Tags: nodejs, express

actualmente estoy aprendiendo NodeJs y trato de hacer una aplicación donde se agrega Bicicleta pero no me deja eliminarlas por más que el mensaje del POST del delete, sea 200 (éxito) pero pero me sale que mi modelo no ha sido modificado (304) por supuesto en la interfaz se ve así que por más que doy click en el botón Eliminar no me elimina el item.

Comparto el código
**../models/bicicleta.js**

```
var Bicicleta = function(id, color, modelo, ubicacion){
this.id = id;
this.color = color;
this.modelo = modelo;
this.ubicacion = ubicacion;
}

Bicicleta.prototype.toString = function(){
    return 'id: ' + this.id + " | color: " + this.color;
}

Bicicleta.allBicis = [];
Bicicleta.add = function(aBici){
    Bicicleta.allBicis.push(aBici);
}

Bicicleta.findById = function(aBiciId){
    var aBici = Bicicleta.allBicis.find(x => x.if == aBiciId);
    if(aBici)
        return aBici;
    else
        throw new Error(`No existe una bicicleta con el id ${aBiciId}`);

}

Bicicleta.removeById = function(aBiciId){
    for(var i = 0; i < Bicicleta.allBicis.length; i++){
        if(Bicicleta.allBicis[i].id == aBiciId){
            Bicicleta.allBicis.splice(i, 1);
            break;
        }

}
//console.log(this.allBicis);
}

var a = new Bicicleta (1, 'rojo', 'urbana', [-12.0557, -76.9360]);
var b = new Bicicleta (2, 'verde', 'urbana', [-12.5557, -76.4360]);

Bicicleta.add(a);
Bicicleta.add(b);


//falla el boton no elimina de la lista
module.exports = Bicicleta;
```

Inserto además el código del controlador 
**../controllers/bicicleta.js**

```
    exports.bicicleta_create_get = function(req, res){
    res.render('bicicletas/create');
}

exports.bicicleta_create_post = function(req, res){
    var bici = new Bicicleta(req.body.id, req.body.color, req.body.modelo);
    bici.ubicacion = [req.body.lat, req.body.lng];
    Bicicleta.add(bici);

    res.redirect('/bicicletas');
}

exports.bicicleta_delete_post = function(req, res){
    Bicicleta.removeById(req.body.id);
    //console.log('Borrado');

    res.redirect('/bicicletas');
```

**../routes/bicicleta.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var bicicletaController = require('../controllers/bicicleta');

router.get('/', bicicletaController.bicicleta_list);
router.get('/create', bicicletaController.bicicleta_create_get);
router.post('/create', bicicletaController.bicicleta_create_post);
router.post('/:id/delete', bicicletaController.bicicleta_delete_post);

module.exports = router;
```

**y este esl código de app.js**

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var bicicletasRouter = require('./routes/bicicletas');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/bicicletas', bicicletasRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
  console.log('Cometiste un error');
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 1):

para empezar no seria lo mejor que un delete lo hagas con un post. en el routes bicicleta deberías tener:

```
router.delete('/:id', controller)
```

y parece ser que el problema es que en el controller estas pillando la id desde del body. Cuando la id la estás pasando por url. Para pillar la id de la url sería lo siguiente:

```
req.params.id
```

Comment: Hice tal cual me recomendaste pero sigue saliendo error.

Comment: Hola, podrías actualizar el código de arriba? mira de poner console logs a ver si te llega la id, así descartamos errores.

Comment: Ya lo hice y no llega la id cuando coloco el console log despues del Bicicleta.removeById(req.body.id); y si lo pongo antes, dice undefined

Comment: recuerda que no tienes que poner req.body.id, es req.params.id